# Extra new line added when variables written to file in Bash

Tags: string, bash

just tinkering with some code that writes variables to a file on a new line. 
But when I do this:

```
echo "${upl}:${xy}" >> NOT_CAPTIONED_IDS.txt
```

Where $upl=someyoutubeid and $xy=somefilename.mp4

I get the line written to the file (someyoutubeid:somefilename.mp4), but an additional newline added after the text.
Is this normal behaviour? Can I stop it from adding that, I still want to append the string on a new line
Python doesnt appear to add the new line with f.write, but I cant use that in this case without a major reworking.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Echo adds a new line. You may use printf if that is not required.

See [Bash's Built-in printf Function](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bashs-built-printf-function) for more examples.